# Passing #define to a void * function

Tags: c

Im trying to pass a #define macro to a function that take a void* argument.

But I'm getting some segmentation fault so i think i did something wrong ;x.

And i cant understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the simple code i made to understand the problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define TEST 0xFFFFu

void f(void *test)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)test);
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;

    f((int*)TEST);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Your program dereferences an (seemingly) arbitrary memory address, what did you except to happen?

Comment: A pointer is a memory address and when you dereference a pointer, you read from that address. What did you expect to be able to read from address 0xFFFF ?

Comment: Please don't make changes to question that invalidate existing answers. I have rolled back your question.

Answer (score 3):

The segmentation fault probably isn't related to the use of `#define`. You call the function with `0xFFFFu`, which is an address your program probably doesn't own, and when you try to dereference it with the `*` operator you go out of the segment, and get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Okay thanks you, now what i try to do is to have 0xFFFF in the variable void *test when i dereference it. Can i do taht in C or it's impossible?

Comment: Re “in the variable void *test”: `void *test` is not a variable. With a `;`, it would be a declaration. If you are writing that as a shorthand referring to the variable `test` while saying its type is `void *`, then you cannot have 0xFFFF when you dereference it because 0xFFFF is not a valid address in the memory of your executing program. Dereferencing it with that value in it will cause a segmentation fault. If you want `*test` to have 0xFFFF in it, then a way to do that is to create an object with 0xFFFF in it and to set `test` to point to it, as in `unsigned x = 0xFFFFu; void *test = &x;`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is valid as far as the C language goes. Please note that "passing a #define" is nonsense, a #define is just a pre-processor keyword which expands to an integer constant in this case.

So what your code actually does is to convert an integer constant 0xFFFF to a pointer, then attempt to de-reference that pointer to access address 0xFFFF.

We may cast from integers to pointers or the other way around, but this might cause misaligned access or instruction traps on some systems. And of course the address must be valid. Apparently your particular system is not amused by an `int` value access from address 0xFFFF and beyond.